# is it possible to add external .db files to iPhone app and change the current DB file dynamically

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, sqlite

I am developing an application where i need to maintain 2 data base files and depending on some run time conditions i should be able to choose one from those two data base files to write or retrieve data.Can any one tell me how to achieve this?also help me in adding an existing .db file with data to the iPhone app.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use two database at same time using one SQLite connection:
1) sqlite3_open_v2(":memory:", &dbConnection, dbFlags, NULL); - this will open `in-memory` database
2) ATTACH DATABASE 'path_to_the_first_sqlite_database' AS 'firstDatabase'
3) ATTACH DATABASE 'path_to_the_second_sqlite_database' AS 'secondDatabase'

And when you will need to select or update something, use database name prefix before table name like: **firstDatabase.myTable** and **secondDatabase.myTable**

Comment: vote up for your answer.can i do this using core data because i do not have knowledge of using sqlite directly.

Comment: I don'T have knowledge about CoreData, because I don't like it and always used SQLite. Now when you said about that you use it with CoreData I have thought that it's not very good idea to interfere into CoreData data storage management. I think it just won't listen, because internally it uses it's own logic to manage relations and so on

Answer (score 0):

Either you'll access these databases with help. Of a webservice or you'll download them from your server and save them on the iphone.

Ps. Downloading for exemple a sqlite file can be done with a simple `nusrlconnection` where you just pass the URL to the sqlite file on your server